# jQuery Mobile load second page from new html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

Say I wanna load a new html file, with some jQuery pages, like this:

```
$.mobile.changePage("some_page.html");
```

If this html file has two pages inside, how do I load not the first, but the second page?
I Tried

```
$.mobile.changePage("some_page.html#second_page_id");
```

But it doesn't work.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `$.mobile.changePage()` function takes the first div with `data-role="page"` and loads it into the dom with an AJAX call. The best solution is to move the second page to the top of the html code.

Otherwise, if you want to decide to load the first or second page, you could put them in different files.

Maybe there's a way of calling the second page, but i have no idea of how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Dude try to make your second page element `data-url` as `<div data-url="page.html&subpageidentifier">`
 in the target html page. and let me know is that really worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually grab the element you want:

```
//delegate the event binding for some link(s)
$(document).delegate('a.my-link', 'click', function () {

    //show the loading spinner
    $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();

    //make the AJAX request for the link's href attribute
    $.ajax({
        url     : this.href,
        success : function (serverResponse) {

            //get the data-role="page" elements out of the server response
            var $elements = $(serverResponse).find('[data-role="page"]');

            //you can now access each `data-role="page` element in the `$elements` object
            $elements.filter('#page-id').appendTo('body');

            //now use changePage to navigate to the newly added page
            $.mobile.changePage($('#page-id'), { /*options*/ });

            //hide the loading spinner
            $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
        },
        error   : function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { /*Don't forget to handler errors*/ }
    });

    //stop the default behavior of the link, also stop the event from bubbling
    return false;
});
```

But I have to say, with the way jQuery Mobile currently works, you're better off putting each `data-role="page"` elements in a separate document.

Answer (score 0):

ทำแบบนี้ครับ

`<a href="../index.php#two" data-ajax="false" data-transition="fade" data-role="button" data-theme="e" name="out">ออก</a>`

สำคัญคือให้ใส่ data-ajax="false"

คุณก็จะ changepage ได้จากต่างหน้า

Comment: give your answer in English